# Trigger solution polishing manually from callback

Tags: java, cplex

I do not require an optimal solution. The solution process is aborted in an IncumbantCallback when the objective is better than a certain treshold. Now, i'd like to use the CPLEX polishing algorithm, to improve that solution. How is it possible to manually trigger solution polishing for example for a certain time period from the callback to improve the best solution?

Comment: This does not make any sense.  Please rewrite for clarity and provide more context.  What solution process? What is an `IncumbantCallback`?  This almost looks like machine-generated SPAM.

Comment: @JimGarrison These are terms that any advanced cplex developer would probably recognize.  BTW: an IncumbantCallback is a hook that is called by cplex whenever it finds a new feasible solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have wanted to do similar before. I have done a similar thing but not from a callback. I don't think you can start polishing from inside a callback.

When the solve is terminated (e.g by your callback) you should be able to change the cplex parameters and call solve again, so maybe set a very short time limit for cplex and set a polish time, and call solve again. You could just polish after you achieve a certain gap of course without needing to do anything fancy.